# Order image from freelancer

Tags: publications, ethics

I am writing a journal paper. In order to illustrate my work, I need to include an image of the whole system that I have built. The problem is that I am not very talented to make good images, so I would like to hire a freelancer to create a professional image. My questions are:

- Is it allowed to add an image that was not done by me?
- Is it ethical?
- If yes, what kind of contract I need to sign with the freelancer so that all the rights belong to me after the payment?

Many thanks.

Comment: https://freelancing.stackexchange.com

Comment: In my opinion is totally ethical.  This has nothing to do with issues as referencing, copyright, acknowledgement and the like. Is like you contact a native speaker and good writer to improve your paper.  I have never done.  But I wouldn't feel being unethical to have, say, a British wife improving my paper English. This is what I feel and what I guess. It will be unethical to be coauthor for just making a nice cover, instead.  And this happens :)

Comment: That's a good question, I think leaving ethical matter aside, you should really contact someone/somewhere with legal background.

Answer (score 11):

In order:

1) Yes, if you paid for it or referenced it

2) Yes, if you paid for it or referenced it

3) your contract should say something like "copyright or all rights pass to client", BUT that may be a question for the Law stack...

Many images on many documents papers etc are done by professional artists for exactly that reason. They like / want the work as well...

Comment: I don't think that paying for it removes the need to reference.

Comment: @Arno may well depend on the contract don't you think?

Comment: No. Rather, if the contract stipulates any particular acknowledgments, then these need to happen. But even if the artist doesn't care about them, I would still see some kind of ethical obligation to the scientific community to credit them in the paper.

Comment: @Arno it is possible to commission an image and purchase ALL the rights for the work... in which case there is no attribution to be made. When you see adverts for toothpaste do they show the Marketing company that designed it? No, the whole point is the product...

Comment: Advertisements are not academic publications. Ethical norms differ. While this may be a gray area for pictures, consider full-on ghostwriting to see this.

Comment: [This paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10021-016-0103-y) came to mind as an example of using a freelanced image (page 675). Looks like they included "designed by XXX" but I don't see the company listed in the references.

Comment: Also check the journal copyright rules just in case

Comment: IMHO an acknowledgement like for a technician who did not contribute intellectually to the paper but did help, say, by keeping your animals/instruments/samples/data happy is the way to go. (To state the obvious, both the technician and the graphic artist nevertheless need to be paid for their work). This is anyways hat we did when a secretary (employee) helped with illustrations for a paper.